# SQL Visual Fox pro 9 - After inserting record some chars code are changed in database (e.g. "À" => "A")

Tags: sql, database, adodb, visual-foxpro

I am connecting to Visual FoxPro 9 SQL database and I need to be able to update and insert records in a table. The table I am trying to work with has column with type CHAR(5).

The problem is that some characters in string I am passing are not stored properly like "À" is after insert or update stored as "A"

There is a desktop app using this database and creating record from there stores those special characters correctly in database. (BTW I don't know how they connect to DB and how they calling insert statement)

I am connecting to database like this:

```
Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=${source};
```

*(using Nodejs with node-adodb)*

And my update for example looks like this:

```
UPDATE vykd01s SET cdok = "taazñ";
```

In this example I try to set value for the column to "taazñ" but it is stored as "taazn" but from UI if I set this value it is stored correctly as "taazñ"

A try many solutions like casting the value but nothing works.

This is some information about the column I was able to get

```
    TABLE_CATALOG: null,
    TABLE_SCHEMA: null,
    TABLE_NAME: 'vykd01s',
    COLUMN_NAME: 'cdok',
    COLUMN_GUID: null,
    COLUMN_PROPID: null,
    ORDINAL_POSITION: 2,
    COLUMN_HASDEFAULT: false,
    COLUMN_DEFAULT: null,
    COLUMN_FLAGS: 88,
    IS_NULLABLE: false,
    DATA_TYPE: 129,
    TYPE_GUID: null,
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: 5,
    CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: 5,
    NUMERIC_PRECISION: null,
    NUMERIC_SCALE: null,
    DATETIME_PRECISION: null,
    CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG: null,
    CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA: null,
    CHARACTER_SET_NAME: null,
    COLLATION_CATALOG: null,
    COLLATION_SCHEMA: null,
    COLLATION_NAME: null,
    DOMAIN_CATALOG: null,
    DOMAIN_SCHEMA: null,
    DOMAIN_NAME: null,
    DESCRIPTION: null
```

So in conclusion I need the string I am passing to update or insert statement needs to be stored equally in the database (with same char codes).

Comment: If you're trying to store Unicode characters, go read this: https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/foxunicode/foxunicode.html

Answer (score 0):

If it works from the UI then please look at the Code Page used in the UI (see function CPCURRENT() in the help) and use the same Code Page in your VFP OLEDB connection string - add CODEPAGE=nnnn into it.